How to tell new grad advisor that I need to transfer after I just picked his university
So I recently chose between two schools. On the surface they looked really similar but one of them (school 1) was offering my degree in 4.5 years instead of 6 and also had some other specialized classes I was interested in. School 2 was also very far away from family and I wasn’t too sure I wanted to make such a big change. After accepting the offer at school 1, I was told by another academic advisor at school 1 that I wouldn’t be able to do my degree in 4.5 years (it would be more like 5-6) and that with field work I would be doing taking some of the specialized courses I wanted to take wouldn’t be possible. Additionally I found out that I wouldn’t be able to afford the tuition for the last year or 2 of my degree.
So now I’m thinking of transferring to school 2 next year. I have a relationship with an advisor at that school and she also knows my current advisor at school 1. I’m just unsure of how to tell my advisor at school 1 that I’m now wanting to transfer after just recently making the decision to go to his school just one month ago. I truthfully just didn’t weigh my pros and cons well enough and didn’t get all of the info I could have before making my decision and want to tell him without seeming like I didn’t think things through. He’s also a great resource for my research and I don’t want to lose a valuable connection.
Any advice on when to go about telling him and how I should say it?

Have you talked to your advisor about all of these things already?

Not yet, he's been doing field work out of the country so I haven't been able to get in contact while I've been learning all of these things

First, you should tell him about these issues. He may have a better solution than transferring. There's no guarantee that you won't have issues at your new institution.

Do you believe everything school 2 told you still? Is that a belief or based on more information you have gotten? Perhaps their program takes 7 years, etc…

It's a belief with school 2. I've gotten more things in writing from them about it and have talked to multiple students and advisors since finding everything out about school 1. The biggest thing about transferring is that I'm on a limited fellowship and don't want to be wasting more time and money at school 1 than I have to while in a program that isn't covering all of the things I want/was told I would get out of my degree.

Does school 2 even still commit to accept you into their program?

Yep! Confirmed from them I can come next fall
